# How to write the Universal Gravitational Constant in Swift

Tags: swift

The universal gravitational constant is

> G = 6,6726 * 10 ^-11

How to express this in Swift programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
let g = 6.6726e-11
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID323